# Why the name 'Salagrama' shila?

Tags: vishnu, puranas

Why are the Vishnu Silas found from Gandaki river called 'Salagrama' Silas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found one reference in the Varaha Purana.

Shalagram got his name from a Muni called Shalakayan. Or it got it's name from a type of tree called Shal tree ([Shorea Robusta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorea_robusta)).

Quoting from [this PDF](https://ia601306.us.archive.org/1/items/ShivaPurana/Varaha%20Purana.pdf):

> Prithvi requested lord Varaha to shed light on the famous penance
>   which sage Shalankayan had performed. Lord Varaha narrated the
>   following tale- "Long long ago sage Shalankayan did an austere penance
>   to please me (lord Vishnu). There was a 'sal' tree nearby and the sage
>   was ignorant of the fact that I dwell in that sacred tree. When I
>   appeared, he requested me to bless him with a divine son who had
>   qualities like lord Shiva. I revealed to him that his son
>   (Nandikeshwar) had already manifested and was presently staying at
>   'Vraja' (Mathura). I also revealed to him that although I was present
>   in the 'sal' tree but he was unware of this fact because of his
>   ignorance. In course of time, this very place became famous as
>   'Shalgram tirth'. A devotee who makes a pilgrimage to this holy place
>   is liberated from all kinds of worldly bondages.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Rickross, the Ahnic-Kritya quotes from Vishnu-Dharmottara-Purana

> Salankayan Muni while meditating on Vishnu saw a Shala Tree appearing in front of him. Sri Vishu appeared under the tree and told him : I am going to appear in the Gandaki river as shila.So the Silas are known as Salagrama.

[image]

Comment: not readable scripture reference