# What is the exact literal translation of the word "Shaligram."?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, meaning, translation

As we all know, [Shaligram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaligram) Shila is the symbol which represents Lord Vishnu just like a Shiva Linga represents Lord Shiva.

But, i want to know what is the literal word meaning or translation of the word Shaligram. Because everytime i search for the meaning it always comes as Shaligram means Lord Vishnu.

Well, i know Shaligram Shila means Lord Vishnu but I wanna know why he is called Shaligram or why the mountain/stone/fossil is called as Shaligram and not something else. Because every name has meaning. Like Narayana means the one wvose abode (ayana) is water (nara), Hari means who take away (pain, sorrow, sins, etc etc)(Haran), Vishnu means the pervasive one or the world (Visva), and so on.

**(Note.: I know the story. So, no need tell it. Just wana know the meaning behind the name and why its called like that according to sanatani scriptures.).**

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/33080/4732

Comment: Though, i do have a theory like if we nreak Shaligram into Shalin + Gram. Shalin can mean modesty (Sri), or good people, etc and gram can mean village or abode. So, it can also mean the one who is the abode of Sri or good people or whose abode are sri or good people. Its, just a theory. Do, i want scriptural reference. ..

Comment: Well, @Rickross i searched for it but msy be due to spelling difference it didn't came up in search but still it not totally same as i have also asked for the literal translation of it which was also not given in the answers. Like why shaligram. Shal part was explained but gram part was not. Prd..

Comment: Yes true ... @Savdy

Comment: @Rickross, read the comment again i have edited it. So, ots kinda mix but not same. Though i have asked for the "why" shaligram but my original question is the "literal translation". So, its totally original question with some mix in it. Prd..

Comment: It's ok .. also I have not close voted @Savdy

Comment: Yup, @Rickross man its ok misunderstanding happens. N closing vote doesn't matters. Quality of question does. Anyways, man cya and tc. ..

Comment: As Savdy said ancient name mukthinath kshetra is shaligram.. village where shila of shaligram is found.

Comment: Good, that my theory was correct. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahnik Kritya, 3rd Khanda, Vishnu Puja Vidhi, from Vishnu Dharmottara Upa Purana.

Etymology of the word Shalagram - Shalankaran Muni was looking for Vishnu and suddenly saw the appearance of a sal tree in front of him.  After a while, Vishnu appeared under him and said - I have just started to produce rocks in the river.  This is the rock Vishnu's name is Shalgram.  — Vishudharthottara Pale (Salvrikshasamipe) Village.

Comment: Could you also specify which chapter and verses from Vishnu Dharmottara Upa Purana?

Comment: Yes, sure, it's Ahanik Kritya from Third Khanda, Vishnu Puja Vidhi part. I have edited and also inserted it in my answer. I hope that is helpful.